# Second page getting stuck when scanning multiple pages using Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, scanning, wia

I'm encountering an issue with my C# application when using the Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) API to scan multiple pages from a scanner device. Specifically, after scanning the first page successfully, the scanner becomes unresponsive or gets stuck when scanning the second page.

When attempting to scan multiple pages using the WIA API in C#, the scanner freezes or becomes unresponsive after scanning the first page. This prevents me from successfully completing the scanning process for all pages.

```
try
{
    // Loop through pages and acquire images
    while (HasMorePages)
    {
        // Acquire the image for the next page
        ImageFile imageFile = (ImageFile)_wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(scannerDevice.Items[1], formatID, false);

        // Process the scanned image
        // For example, save it to a file
        imageFile.SaveFile("scanned_page_" + pageNumber + ".jpg");

        // Check if there are more pages to scan
        // Update HasMorePages and pageNumber variables accordingly
    }
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
{
    // Handle COM exceptions
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle other exceptions
}
```

After about a minute and a half the scanner sends an error that it is jammed. another error i get is the scanner is busy.

This code works when using the following scanners:
fujitsu fi-7160,
fujitsu fi-7460,
fujitsu fi-6140z.
The scanner I am trying to use now is the Ricoh fi-8170. Can some one help me?

I need this application to be able to scan more then one page without freezing up.